# Semantic React Dropdown does not display values despite setState

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui-react

I have a dropdown in an Edit page where i set it value to be equal to this.state.value. Upon render of page, this.state.value is set to empty string. Then on componentDidMount, I call an api which fetch the old values of member to be edited. I set the state of each component with this response values of api call.

However upon render, I cannot display the value of the dropdown. I console.log the state after second render and I saw state has indeed change. The values of the other component are displayed successfully except for the dropdown.

I need help or idea on why the dropdown refuse to show the value upon api fetch.

Comment: What is the dropdown option JSON and api call response.?

Comment: Can you show the value that your fetched as JSON? Did you parse it?

Comment: can you post some code, so we will be able to help you in a better way.. You can recreate the issue with a similar code..try to create it here so it will be easy https://codesandbox.io/s/pp0jl9jzq